# remove white space at the the bottom of the page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have got a jQueryMobile page that adds some white space after the content. How do I remove it? I know I have not got a footer in the page, is that the reason? Any advice much appreciated.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="message"></div>
            <a data-role="none" href="" id="btn_loginEmail" class="button"></a>
            <a data-role="none" href="" id="btn_loginFacebook" class="button"></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it is not a problame mail me your pages and I will fix it for you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: IF anyone is stuck with this, please see answers on a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682642/jquery-mobile-and-iphone-white-space-in-the-bottom-of-the-page/34047696#34047696

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean white space??

I've tried your page and it works just fine

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9KYy/)

You mean the space between header bar and first element inside content (in above case the button)?

Then you can do style as below

```
.ui-content{
    margin-top: -23px;
}
```

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9KYy/1/)

Comment: thanks for your answer.but i dont think i presented my problem properly. The white space appears after the content,i think its because there is not enought content.its something similar to the problem this person had http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/5922/jquerymobile.png But in my case I dont have a footer. The weird thing is if the orientation changes to landscape the white space disappears and come back when its in potratit

Answer (score 0):

if u are using jqm 1.2.0. In min.css, change min-height to 400px in ui-page{min-height:420px}. Hope it works for you!!