# jquery mobile and iphone - white space in the bottom of the page

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile webpage. It looks good on desktop browsers, and also on android.

But in iphone's safari, I have a weird white space in the bottom of the page. It looks like a problem with the min-height of the .ui-page, because the white space is as height as the title-bar + url-bar of safari.

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I found the problem: It was:

```
 html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    position: relative !important;
 }
```

Comment: It has to do with `ui-content` height. it occurs when `data-role=content` has different `data-theme` than `data-role=page`.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code fix your problem.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/KmYgP/)**

```
// Get height of the document
var screen = $(document).height();

// Get height of the header
var header = $('[data-role=header]').height();

// Get height of the footer
var footer = $('[data-role=footer]').height();

// Simple calculation to get the remaining available height
var content = screen - header - footer;

// Change the height of the `content` div
$('[data-role=content]').css({'height': content });
```

Comment: it looks like the loader div is causing it. try this `$('div.ui-loader').hide();` or `remove();`. but try `hide();` first. @leftjustified

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with  min-height attribute in  min.css. 
change

ui-page { min-height:"400px" }

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting on an old question, but I recently got stuck with this.

Turned out the problem was caused in some browsers by JS functions people provide for hiding the address bar.

such as

```
function hideAddressBar(){
  if(document.documentElement.scrollHeight<window.outerHeight/window.devicePixelRatio)
    document.documentElement.style.height=(window.outerHeight/window.devicePixelRatio)+'px';
  setTimeout(window.scrollTo(1,1),0);
}
window.addEventListener("load",function(){hideAddressBar();});
window.addEventListener("orientationchange",function(){hideAddressBar();});
```